# Salt: manage 100+ virtualenvs on one host

Tags: python, virtualenv, salt-stack

How can we structure the salt state tree to be able to run `highstate` for one virtualenv out of a large number running on a host?

We run virtualenvs for development and in production, using fabric. We want to switch from fabric to salt. Everything works nice, except that `highstate` takes too long. We have 100+ virtualenvs on one host, and caling `highstate` would update 100+ virtualenvs.

Comment: can you tell how long it takes?

Comment: @dahrens sorry, I have no numbers at the moment. But speed is only one concern. The other is: Addressability. I want to be able to update one particular virtualenv without touching the other virtualenvs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`salt '*' state.highstate`

always applies **all** states to your minion. It depends on your states why it takes quite a while until highstate returns.

It is possible to organize the deployment by using seperate states for each venv. Individual states can be applied like that:

`salt '*' state.sls venv1`

A simple salt tree might look like this.

```
    .
    +-- salt
    |   +-- _prereq.sls
    |   +-- venv1.sls
    |   +-- venv2.sls
    |   +-- top.sls
```

If you need stuff to be done as prerequisite for each venv in the same way you might use something like that:

**_prereq.sls**

```
install_something:
  pkg.installed:
    pkgs: ['foo', 'bar']
```

**venv1.sls**

```
include:
  - _prereq

myvenv_state:
  virtualenv.managed:
    - system_site_packages: False
    - requirements: salt://requirements.txt
    - require:
      - sls: _prereq
```

I prefer to be able to highstate my minions without thinking about it, so i try to avoid addressable states. But it might fit your needs.

You might also want to have a look at [salt.states.virtualenv](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.virtualenv_mod.html)

Comment: I guess `salt '*' state.sls venv1` instead of highstate should work. If venv1 and venv2 share a common set of requirements, how to write this (without code duplication)?

Comment: you might create another state with the requirements and include that state in each venv like [explained in salt docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#require-an-entire-sls-file)

Comment: keep in mind that you want to be able to highstate your minions properly. how long does it actually take to highstate them?